# Can Spring Cloud Stream can send message to the other messageChannel which in the same application with StreamBridge?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

purpose:

1. I want to test the feature "spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination" that on the document "https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_stream_sendto_destination"
2. And then I don't want to test it with the example with the Function Bean, because I want to send the message with http, but Function Bean need the explicit destination exposed by the outer broker.
3. I do know I can achieve it with the "StreamBridge.send('dynamicDestinationName')". But I really want to test the "sendto.destination" can achieve the same effect or not.

Trying procession:

1. the controller http endpoint ready.

```
    @GetMapping("/test/dynamic/destination/{destination}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void dynamicDestination(@PathVariable("destination") String destination) {
        log.info("route to dynamic[{}]", destination);
        // First send it to the Binding of Stream inside the stream first, and then send it to the Broker end Destination according to the Headers' consumer
        streamBridge.send("dynamicDestFunc-in-0", destination);
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public Function<String, Message<String>> dynamicDestFunc() {
        return value -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(value + "_payload").setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", value).build();
    }
```

2. application.yaml ready.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: xx.xx.xx.xx:9092
      bindings:
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: O2_TEST_TOPIC
          content-type: application/json
    function:
      definition: functionRouter;dynamicDestFunc
```

3. debug that it will throw the NullPointerException because the producerProperties is null!

[NullPointerException throwed when StreamBridge#resolveDestination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFFUQ.png)

finally, Can Spring Cloud Stream can send message to the other messageChannel which in the same application with StreamBridge?

**Can Message channel connected to the other message Channel without binder/outer broker?**

like **channelA outputBinding -> channelB inputBinding -> channelB outputBinding -> dynamicDestination exposed by the outer broker**

**for the another Quesion: confused to use the *KafkaExtendedBindingProperties* and *KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties***

here is my application.yml which refer my thought

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
#        default:
#          consumer:
#            startOffset: latest
#            resetOffsets: true
#            autoCommitOffset: true
        binder:
          brokers: xx.xx.xx.xx:9092
        bindings:
          testAutoCommit-in-0:
            consumer:
              startOffset: latest
              resetOffsets: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
              configuration: { request.timeout.ms: "600000" }
      bindings:
        testAutoCommit-in-0:
          destination: O2_TEST_TOPIC
          group: testAutoCommit_GROUP
    function:
      definition: testAutoCommit
```

Comment: The `sendto.destination` is a feature of the framework. Why would you want to test something that has already been tested by the framework?

Comment: I am waiting for your answer for a long time, sir! First, thanks for your patient answer.

I just want to implement "dynamic sending feature" and explore the multiple ways to implement it, so that I tested The sendto.destination 
and test could implement the same feature or not.

Comment: By this opportunity， I want to ask the another question and really hope for your guidance again! 
I am confused to use the "KafkaExtendedBindingProperties" and "KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties". From my personal understanding，
the "xxxExtendedBindingProperties" is for the binding dimension, and the default kafka properties can use "spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default"，
so the "xxxbinderConfigurationProperties" for what? Is it the same as the "kafka.default"?

Comment: There are common binder properties (properties that apply for all binders) and there are properties specific to each binder (e.g.. Kafka or Rabbit) and can be different.

Comment: Please allow me to talk about my research background! My company developed a component to management the message(event).
The component called "xxx-event" can achieve the dynamic sending and dynamic consume, dynamic update the prducer/consumer config and support to
toggle the event broker type(like kafka or rabbitmq)....

So I learn the Spring Cloud Stream with which "xxx-event" used recently, and I have been a really big fan of yours.

Comment: After reading your explain below，I am still comfused to the "KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties" and "KafkaExtendedBindingProperties".Are they any different? I think they are both of the kafka.  Are there exists any priority? finally, Thank you again for your patience answer!

Comment: I think the "ExtendedBindingProperties" can distinguish by the binding dimension, and the BinderConfigurationProperties" apply the configuration to all bindings, am I right?

Comment: I just thought about it again, the bindingServiceProperties "spring.cloud.stream" is the top configuration property. And its "bindings" and  "binders" define the secondary property.  Bindings property can apply to each binder. and binder property can apply to each binding.

Comment: And the KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties is just define the special binder property(e.g.. Kafka), but its configurations can apply to each binding.

Answer (score 2):

Binder and Binding are two distinct concepts in Spring Cloud Stream.

*Binding* - is the mechanism that connects Binder components (e.g., message listeners) with your application (e.g., Function).

*Binder* - is a mechanism by which Spring Cloud Stream connects to a target system (e.g., Kafka, Rabbit etc).

A good analogy would be *Binder is the cable connecting you to the network* and *Binding is an internet site available in the network you are connected to*. And as two different concepts each has its own set of configurations.

Comment: I added my answer for helping to understand your answer, wish you can review it in your spare time! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg Zhurakousky

At first, SCS mentioned below means the "Spring Cloud Stream".

Thanks for your answer, and I want to describe my understanding of your answer for helping others to understand the binding and binder properties quickly.

just like that author "Oleg Zhurakousky" said, binding and binder are two distinct component in SCS.

the *binder* can help us connect to the internet like a *"router"*.

the *binding* can help us connect to the website in the internet like a *"browser"*.

So *Binder Configuration* define the broker address and port like *(the ip address of router table)*.

Also, *Binding Configuration* define the more concrete address(which called destination in SCS), just like the *(http url on the browser)*

But I was still in a confused when I try hard to describe a clear mapping betweeen the kafka configuration and the configuration(Binder/Binding) in SCS.

I try to describe the mappings as following:

1. bootstrap.servers -> brokers ,of binder properties (*KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties*)

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
// build KafkaProducer
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties)
```

so I think the mapping is ***producer properties param -> binder properties***

2. topic -> destination , of binding properties (*BindingProperties*)
3. enable.auto.commit -> of binder properties(I guess) *(KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties#KafkaProperties#Consumer.enableAutoCommit)*

But another explain is also right. It is of binding properties , in the KafkaExtendedBindingProperties#bindings

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          testAutoCommit-in-0:
            consumer:
              startOffset: latest
              resetOffsets: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
              configuration:
                request.timeout.ms: 60000
```

for understanding the relation of binder and bindingProperties, I even list the following list:

- BindingProperties
- ExtendedBindingProperties(getExtendedConsumerProperties(bindingName),getExtendedProducerProperties(bindingName)）
- AbstractExtendedBindingProperties
- BinderSpecificPropertiesProvider（getProducer()和getConsumer()）=> KafkaBindingProperties#KafkaProducerProperties，KafkaBindingProperties#KafkaConsumerProperties）
- BinderProperties
- ProducerProperties
- ConsumerProperties

binder-kafka-core：（kafka binder实现包下的配置类，定义了Kafka专属配置）

- KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties（"spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder"）
- KafkaConsumerProperties
- KafkaProducerProperties
- KafkaTopicProperties
- KafkaBindingProperties
- KafkaExtendedBindingProperties（"spring.cloud.stream.kafka"）

But I finally gave up!

And I think I just need to find out the configurationProperties provided for us in SCS , and needn't to figure out the complicated properties class relationship....

Like the list below:

Simply,from the point of view of use ，I just need to find out the properties when I try to configure or update the kafka properties.
the SCS configuration like following:

- BindingServiceProperties （"spring.cloud.stream"）
- Map<String, BindingProperties> bindings ("spring.cloud.stream.bindings")
- Map<String, BinderProperties> binders ("spring.cloud.stream.binders")
- KafkaProperties （"spring.kafka"）
- KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties（"spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder"）
- KafkaExtendedBindingProperties#DEFAULTS_PREFIX （"spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default"）

I do this for helping my colleagues and I can configure the properties What we need quickly without understand the complicate detail behind the source code.

But really understanding the relationshop between the binder and binding will help you configure the properties quickly, because you can location the correct SCS configuration property which you need as quickly as possible.

I worked < 2 two years in China, and hope to write a beautiful code like the author "Oleg Zhurakousky" at the future!